# extract the DIV outerHTML through contents jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div class="product">
   <span class=itemlist><!-- Shows Results for Fish --></span>
    Category:Fish
    <br>Product: Salmon Atlantic
    <br>Specie: Salmo salar
    <br>Form: Steaks
</div>

<div class="product">
    <span class=itemlist><!-- Shows Results for Crustacean --></span>
     Category: Crustacean
     <br>Product: Shrimp Cultured Vannamei White
     <br>Specie: Penaeus vannamei
     <br>Form: PTO/PDTO     
</div>
```

All I want is to extract the `DIV` `.outerHTML()` whose `SPAN` `.content()` is equal to `<!-- Shows Results for Crustacean -->` for this is the only identifier I think I could have. All classes for `DIV` and `SPAN` are similar.

What should be the jQuery code for this?

the Output should only be:

```
<div class="product">
        <span class=itemlist><!-- Shows Results for Crustacean --></span>
         Category: Crustacean
         <br>Product: Shrimp Cultured Vannamei White
         <br>Specie: Penaeus vannamei
         <br>Form: PTO/PDTO
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var pro=$('.product span:contains(Crustacean)');
console.log(pro.closest('.product')[0].outerHTML);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/NCujZ/)

**Updated** `Hide` all `div.product` except having `span Crustacean`

```
var pro=$('.product span:contains(Crustacean)');
$('.product').hide();
pro.closest('.product').show();
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/NCujZ/2/)

Comment: the demo also show the Fish product. all i want is to get the Crustacean product

Comment: @Onimax see in `console` in my `Demo`

Comment: how can i output it on the page instead of using console.log ?

Comment: @Onimax see my `updated answer` and `demo` or http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/NCujZ/2/

Comment: This things worked on me. Thank you @Rohan Kumar.. hope i could give you at least 2 check marks for this.

Answer (score 1):

If the span has the context `Crustacean` displayed then try

```
$('.product:contains(Crustacean)')[0].outerHTML
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wnZrP/)

Comment: can u make it running on jsfiddle? i tried this but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.product span.itemlist").contents().each(function(){
     if (this.nodeType == 8) {
        if(this.data.contains('Shows Results for Crustacean'))
        {
            // do what ever you need here
        }
      }
  });
});
```